# Change ProgressDialog color (lower API) Android

Tags: android, api, colors, customization, progressdialog

Hello In my app I have simple progressDialog. I use some simple code to manage colors of it but there is a problem for api lower than 21.

Normally it should looks like

[image]

but for lower api it looks

[image]

There is a way to made it looks like first image ?

My code for progressDialog

```
 @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogId) {
switch (dialogId) {
            case PLEASE_WAIT_DIALOG:
                final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dialogWysylka));
                dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.dialogWysylkaDol));
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                return dialog;
    }
```

and xml for manage colors :

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/brownmuseum</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Android O, ProgressDialog is now officially deprecated. An alternative is approach is suggested

> This class was deprecated in API level O. Use a progress indicator such as ProgressBar inline inside of an activity rather than using this modal dialog.

You can use

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

for below API

Comment: just use this one only.

Comment: if I use that It wont be looks like on first image :)

Comment: using ProgressDialog, u will get like that only. Other wise u need to create some custom dialogs

Answer (score 0):

Try this code getting IndeterminateDrawable and setColorFilter.

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage(getString(R.string.progress_message));
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
progress.setCancelable(false);
//if lower API 21
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Drawable drawable = new ProgressBar(this).getIndeterminateDrawable().mutate();
    drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    progress.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
}

progress.show();
```

Comment: hmm it won't change anything.